# [Oracle Goldengate]Extract process abended: OGG-00662 OCI Error ORA-01435: user does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, goldengate

I created an Oracle GoldenGate EXTRACT process in Multitenant.

```
EXTRACT ES2K_SIT
USERID C##OGG@192.168.2.3:1521/L1DB，PASSWORD ****
EXTTRAIL /nas/ogg_oracle/dirdat/S2K_SIT/e1
DISCARDFILE /home/ogg/ogg19c/dirrpt/es2k_discard.dsc,APPEND
STATOPTIONS REPORTFETCH
NOCOMPRESSUPDATES
NOCOMPRESSDELETES
GETUPDATEBEFORES
TABLE L1DBPDB24.frms.TABLE1;
```

It can work, but it exits abnormally **every 6 hours**. The following is the error log.

```
OGG-00662 OCI Error ORA-01435:user does not exist.
OGG-02078 Extract encountered a fatal error in a processing thread and is abending.
```

I am certain that I have created C##OGG user in both CDB and PDB. I suspect it's a problem with user permissions, but I have checked that all necessary permissions exist. My OGG version is 19.0.0.4 and oracle version is 19c. Please help me.

I have already granted DBA privilege to C##OGG and excuted dbms_goldengate_auth.grant_admin_privilege command. But they're useless. My problem only occurs in multitenant Oracle.

Comment: You should remove your true IP address from your question, as you appear to have just advertised your database's location and port number to the entire world.